# Pointers/Class C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this pointers/class problem and I am stuck with creating a function call `add(string t)`. What is the best way to write the add(string t) function? I cannot modify inside main(). This is just a silly code that you move your train around. Here is an example of the output:

```
Current train: Engine

Do you wish to go to the (n)ext train, (p)revious train, (a)dd a train, or (q)uit?
a

Which train is this?
4

Current train: Engine

Previous train: 4

Do you wish to go to the (n)ext train, (p)revious train, (a)dd a train, or (q)uit?
a

Which train is this?
1
Current train: Engine

Previous train: 1

Do you wish to go to the (n)ext train, (p)revious train, (a)dd a train, or (q)uit?
p
```

Any tip is greatly appreciated. Thanks! Happy Holiday.

```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  class train
  {
     private:
     string s;
     train* next_train;
     train* previous_train;
     train* has_next;
     train* has_previous;

     public:
     train(string name);
     string getName();
     train* nextTrain();
     train* previousTrain();
     train* hasNext();
     train* hasPrevious();
     void add(train *t);
  };

  int main()
  {
     train engine = train("Engine");
     train* current = &engine;
     string choice;
     do
     {
         if(current -> hasNext())
         {
           cout << "Next train: " << current -> nextTrain() -> getName() <<  
                                       endl;
         }
         cout << "Current train: " << current -> getName() << endl;

         if(current -> hasPrevious())
         {
        cout << "Previous train: " << current -> previousTrain() -> getName()  
         << endl;
         }

        cout << "Do you wish to go to the (n)ext train, (p)revious train,  
        (a)dd a train, or (q)uit?\n";
        getline(cin,choice);

        if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'n' && current -> hasNext())
        {
        current = current -> nextTrain();
        }
        else if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'p' && current -> hasPrevious())
        {
        current = current -> previousTrain();
        }
        else if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'a')
        {
        cout << "Which train is this?\n";
        string name;
        getline(cin, name);
        current->add(name);
        }           

    }while(tolower(choice[0]) != 'q');
 }

  train::train(string name)
  {
    s = name;
  }

  string train::getName()
  {
    return s;
  }

  train* train::nextTrain()
  {
   return next_train;
  }

  train* train::previousTrain()
  {
    return previous_train;
  }

  train* train::hasNext()
  {
    return has_next;
  }

 train* train::hasPrevious()
 {
   return has_previous;
 }

 void train::add(string *t)
 {
  train* current;
  current = &t;
 }
```

Comment: What is your question? You just want someone to write that function for you?

Comment: I don't grok `has_next` or `has_previous`. Where are you going with this?

Comment: @CareyGregory That was nice of you to ask me that rhetorical question if I just want someone to write that function for me. If so, I can pay someone to do that rather get on here. Do you understand? Sometimes, I think when people post a problem, it does not have to be in the question type. In this case, well if you think I need to post a question, it will be: what is the best way to come up with the add function in my code? Not "can you write the add function for me?" Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't a rhetorical question. Right now your question has 4 close votes and 4 downvotes because it's considered off topic. Your opinions on how questions should be formulated are irrelevant since that's defined by the forum, not you. I recommend reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and learning how to formulate a good question. Do so and you'll get answers rather than downvotes.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a doubly-linked list. This list uses a node class, in this case you can call it `train`. Each node has a `name`, as well as `next` and `previous` node. The list class will store the nodes.

The example below is a simple version where all the members are `public`. You can improve it by declaring `next`, `prev`, `head`, `tail` as `private`, then provide `public` methods to access them.

The list should also cleanup after itself. In `add` method there is a call to `train *node = new train(s)`. This memory should be freed in destructor using `delete`. You have to walk the list and delete the memory for each node.

See also these references:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list
http://www.dailyfreecode.com/Code/double-linked-list-cpp-3422.aspx

```
class train
{
public:
    string name;
    train *next, *prev;
    train(const string &s) {name = s; next = prev = nullptr;}
};

class linked_list
{
public:
    train *head, *tail;
    linked_list() { head = tail = nullptr;  }
    linked_list() { /*add cleanup routine*/ }
    train* add(const string &s)
    {
        train *node = new train(s);
        if(!head) {
            head = tail = node;
        }
        else {
            node->prev = tail;
            tail->next = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        return node;
    }
};

int main()
{
    linked_list list;
    train *walk, *node = nullptr;
    string name;
    while(true) {
        char choice = 'a';
        if(node) {
            cout << "(A)dd, (L)ist, (N)ext, (P)revious, (Q)uit ?\n";
            cin >> choice;
            choice = tolower(choice);
        }

        switch(choice) {
        case 'a': 
            cout << "enter name:\n";
            cin >> name;
            node = list.add(name);
            break;
        case 'l': 
            cout << "list:\n";
            walk = list.head;
            while(walk) {
                cout << walk->name << "\n";
                walk = walk->next;
            }
            break;
        case 'n':
            if(node->next) {
                node = node->next;
                cout << "next: " << node->name << "\n";
            }
            break;
        case 'p':
            if(node->prev) {
                node = node->prev;
                cout << "previous: " << node->name << "\n";
            }
            break;
        default: break;
        }
        if(choice == 'q')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `train::add` function. It accepts a `train *` as an argument:

```
 void train::add(train *t)
```

You are attempting to pass it a `std::string` here:

`current->add(name);`

You need to create a new `train` object somehow and pass a pointer to it to `train::add`.

Comment: oh so you mean like void train::add(string *t)? because the add function inside main() takes a string name as an argument.